# Convert function in Matlab into appropriate form

Tags: matlab, function, math

I have written a function `feval` that takes two arguments and spits out a number.

Now I wanted to use the command `integral2` in order to integrate over my function `feval(x,y)`.

The problem seems to be that `integral2` thinks that I have a function that can take two arrays as arguments and apply pairwise operations on them. Unfortunately, this is not the case. My function can only works with 2 numbers and not with full arrays. Is there any standard method to make this work?

Actually, this is my code now and MATLAB claims that 
q = integral2( @(x,y) arrayfun(func_cross_scat,x,y),0,2*pi,0,pi);
my function(feval, that i renamed func_cross_scat does not get enough input arguments)

Comment: (1) you can create a wrapper function that will call your function for all values in a larger array (2) you can use the `.` command where possible (vectorize)

Comment: @TryHard would you mind taking a lot at this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed `integral2` not with `feval`, but with `feval_wrapper` defined as

```
feval_wrapper = @(x,y) arrayfun(feval, x, y)
```

`x` and `y` can now be arrays (of the same size). This works because `arrayfun` calls `feval` for each pair of elements of the input arrays `x`, `y` and gives an array as the result.

As a side comment, "feval" is probably not a good name for your function, because Matlab has a built-in `feval`.

Comment: sorry a problem occured

Comment: yes, as I included in my initial question. matlab says now, that the function does not get any arguments at all. are you sure that you do not need to write arguments there? (you have just written arrayfun(feval,x,y), perhaps one has to write something that suggests that feval has arguments (x,y) itself. but i am not sure about this. therefore i just wanted to ask you whether you are completely sure about your answer?

Comment: @Lipschitz if you read Luis Mendos answer he explains that you should NOT use the name "feval" as this will lead to confusion. Try instead  feval_wrapper = @(x,y) arrayfun(myfunction, x, y)...

Comment: yes, i know and i just used this name here, so that all knew about which function i was talking. so nevertheless, it does not work right.

Comment: @Lipschitz It would be easier to discuss on real code. Could you post what you are doing?

Comment: okay, I want to run the code %%q = integral2( @(x,y)arrayfun(func_cross_scat,x,y),0,2*pi,0,pi); $$                    and the function that is in there looks like this(of course there is more code, but when i try to run the integral2 line)  %%         function [F] = func_cross_scat(theta,phi)  %%            ..... this gives me a ...%%Error using func_cross_scat
Not enough input arguments.%%

Comment: @Lipschitz I don't have the `integral2` function available, but try defining the wrapper function separately: `function_wrapper = @(x,y) arrayfun(func_cross_scat,x,y)` and then `integral2(function_wrapper, 0,2*pi,0,pi)`

Comment: Found the error it has to be: function_wrapper = @(x,y) arrayfun(@func_cross_scat,x,y);
integral2(function_wrapper, 0,2*pi,0,pi)

Comment: THanks to you both, since you gave me the idea with the wrapper